# Nebensatz without verb at the last position (with modal verbs). Why?

Tags: subordinate-clause, modal-verb

The order in the following sentence is ok, right?

> (1) Ich glaube, dass er seine Hausaufgaben früher *hätte* machen können.

Why is it so and not as the following variant?

> (2) Ich glaube, dass er seine Hausaufgaben früher machen können *hätte*.

The principal (conjugated) verb is *hättest*.

- Why isn't it at the last position?
- Does (2) have a different meaning, or is it just wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a special case: The sentence contains an *Ersatzinfinitiv* of a modal verb (namely, *können* instead of *gekonnt*) and the auxiliary verb *haben*. Such a construction requires that the auxiliary is moved in front of the other verbs; version (2) is ungrammatical. (*Machen hätte können* sounds slightly less bad, but still odd.)

See [canoo on *verb clusters in final position of a subordinate clause*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882) for specific other cases where both positions are possible.

Comment: Beim Satzroulette hätte ich *"hätte früher machen können"* gesagt.